# Unity2D: Admob - Reward system

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, reward-system, rewardedvideoad

I'm having problems with my code, you see I imported Google Admob into my project. I integrated the reward system into my AdManager script, using [Github's Plugin Wiki and Documentation](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob). However (in my AdManager script) my rewarding the user function isn't really working, I have a static int from another script that gives my player a boomerang when they pick it up in the game, buy it or receive from watching a video. Below is my AdManager script:

```
public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
  {
     public static AdManager Instance { set; get; }

public string bannerId;
public string videoId;

private void Start()
{
    Instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    Admob.Instance().initAdmob(bannerId, videoId);
    Admob.Instance().setTesting(true);
    Admob.Instance().loadInterstitial();
    Admob.Instance().rewardedVideoEventHandler += onRewardedVideoEvent;

     #endif
 }
public void Reward()
{
    Admob ad = Admob.Instance();
    if (ad.isRewardedVideoReady())
    {
        ad.showRewardedVideo();
    }
    else
    {
        ad.loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-2099082167446861/xxxxxxxxxx");
    }
}

void onRewardedVideoEvent(string eventName, string msg)
{
    WeaponScript.boomerang += 1;
    Debug.Log("Well Done! You have been rewarded one Boomerang!");
    Debug.Log("handler onRewardedVideoEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
  }
}
```

My problem: I built the game and tried it out, watched a video got a reward (boomerang), but when I did it again (watch another reward video) I didn't get another reward (boomerang). Not sure if I'm doing it wrong. Please can anyone help me with my problem. Thank you!

Comment: interesting, what does your logcat say? does it log the stuff in `onRewardedVideoEvent`?

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out